# How does image processing work in Apache Tika

Tags: image-processing, ocr, apache-tika

I'm using Apache Tika to extract text from images. Tika in turn uses tesseract to recognize text. But comparing the output from Tika and Tessaract (which I have also installed as a standalone commandline tool) I've noticed that the former gives much better results than Tesseract alone.
So does Tika use some bundled image preprocessor to improve the image quality prior to calling the bundled Tesseract instance? Or does Tika pass some arguments to Tesseract to improve the results?

Answer (score 1):

I found all arguments, that Tika sends to Tesseract. Most important for improvement of image quality was `--psm 1` ([Page segmentation method](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method))